# How to test on new images provided one training is done to the system

Tags: matlab

Hi [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) is the tutorial I am following.I have successfully applied to my problem statement also.and its successfully detecting what I want.But I want the same trained system to be used for detecting other images also.While detecting on other images I dont want system to get training again.Is it possible.I think so .I could see there is an XML file having data of training steps.Any help please.
Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1):

You need to address better your question. From what I understand you just trained a classifier to detect an object. Now you want to use the trained files to detect the object in other images.

```
det = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('nameOfYourTrainedFile.xml');
img = imread('image.jpg'); % load an instance of your object
bbox = step(det,img); % search for the object
obj = insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',bbox); % mark it
figure; imshow(obj); % display it
```